# Fluent Validation does not work as expected

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-web-api, fluentvalidation

I've been trying to add Fluent Validation to my .NetCore 7 Web API which i follow the Clean Architecture desing pattern. My problem is;
When I directly provide the "Activity" entity to "AbstractValidator" type paramater, validation works but if "CreateActivityCommand.Command" is provided, validation does not work and request returns "200 OK" which it should'nt because the "Title" field is empty.
I've somewhat followed the clean architecture boilerplate by jasontaylordev (https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture), it seems the same logic works for that occasion.

Here is the "CreateActivityCommand" code;

```cs
namespace Application.Activities.Commands.CreateActivity
{
    public class CreateActivityCommand
    {
        public class Command : IRequest<Unit>
        {
            public Activity Activity { get; set; }

        }


        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command, Unit>
        {
            private readonly DataContext _dataContext;

            public Handler(DataContext dataContext)
            {
                _dataContext = dataContext;
            }

            public async Task<Unit> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                _dataContext.Activities.Add(request.Activity);
                await _dataContext.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
                return Unit.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the "CreateActivityCommandValidator" code;

```cs
namespace Application.Activities.Commands.CreateActivity
{
    public class CreateActivityCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateActivityCommand.Command>
    {
        private readonly DataContext _dataContext;

        public CreateActivityCommandValidator(DataContext dataContext)
        {
            _dataContext = dataContext;

            RuleFor(v => v.Activity.Title).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Title is required");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the Activity entity;

```cs
 public class Activity
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Venue { get; set; }
    }
```

I hope my explanation was clear enough. Can't really figure out where is my mistake, thank you for your help.

Comment: Please explain "does not work at all".

Comment: It does not validate the "Title" field and the request just passes without any error

Comment: Please explain it in the question text. Also make sure that the validator actually runs.

Comment: So, does the validator run? And does the validation pipeline throw if validation fails?

Comment: I'm using the autovalidation feature, I do not really know how to check the validator runs or not. It just validate correctly if I provide the entity itself but not when I provide the entity which comes from Command

Comment: I don't know "clean architecture" so I don't know if you can debug the pipeline or if there's some configuration involved. Hope others chime in.

Comment: builder.Services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();
 builder.Services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Program>();

Comment: mine what like this;  services.AddFluentValidationAutoValidation();            services.AddValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<CreateActivityCommandValidator>();